# How do I handle function templates in SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am getting a "Syntax error in input" error using SWIG on the following line of code

```
template<typename T>
void print_vec(std::vector<T> vec, int length = -1);
```

in my .i file, I include the following line

```
%template(print_vec_int) print_vec<int>;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may be because of the `std::vector<T>` argument to the function. Try adding a `%template(int_vector) std::vector<int>` and a `typedef `std::vector<int> int_vector;` (see [Templates](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn30) in the docs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are swigging C++ code, but telling swig it is C. You need to add `-c++` to the swig command line.

```
swig -o x_wrap.cc -c++ -python x.i
```

If you are using SCons, then you need to update the SWIGFLAGS environment variable:

```
env = Environment(SWIGFLAGS=['-c++', '-python'])
```